# Closed sequence for an alternating pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that for a simple sequence like `1,2,4,8,16` it can be represented as a closed sequence

$ x_n = 2^n$

Is it possible to represent a number sequence where you alternate between adding $a$ and multiplying by $m$ as a closed sequence?

eg, The sequence `1,3,6,8,16,18` alternates between adding 2 and multiplying by 2

Can this be expressed in terms of $x_n$ with adder $a$ and multiplier $m$?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A123208

Comment: @JMoravitz Thats brilliant! I'm a coder not a mathematician and ultimately what im trying to do is write some code to generate a whole load of integer sequences. Is there a dataset anywhere on that website which is downloadable?

Comment: Ignore - I found it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider every other term (indexing starts at $t_0=1$),

$$t_{2n+2}=2(t_{2n}+2).$$

Then with $t_{2n}=u_{2n}-4$,

$$u_{2n+2}-4=2(u_{2n}-4+2)$$ or $$u_{2n+2}=2u_{2n},$$

by induction and using $u_0=5$,

$$u_{2n}=5\cdot2^n,$$

$$t_{2n}=5\cdot2^n-4$$

and

$$t_{2n+1}=5\cdot2^n-2.$$

---

If you want a single formula,

$$t_m=5\cdot2^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}-4+2(m\bmod2).$$

Answer (score 0):

Best I can do:  $$ a_n =
\begin{cases}
5\times 2^k-4,  & \text{if $n=2k$ } \\
5\times 2^k-2, & \text{if $n=2k+1$}
\end{cases}$$

Proof:  clearly $a_0=1,a_1=3$ as desired. We also remark that $a_{2k+1}=a_{2k}+2$ as desired.  All that remains is to show that $$a_{2k}=5\times 2^k-4=2\times\left(5\times2^{k-1}-2\right)=2\times a_{2(k-1)+1}$$ and we are done.